# Weekly mobile usage

Tags: settings, data-monitoring

I have a weekly payment cycle for mobile data. The data usage settings are limited to a monthly billing cycle and data warning. What can I do to monitor data usage on a weekly cycle?

Answer (score 1):

Withe the App [MyDataManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm) it is possible to monitor mobile data usage in 4 ways :

1. Monthly
2. Weekly
3. Daily
4. Custom

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could achieve the same with [3g Watchdog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdog&hl=en), giving a breakdown usage history per day/week etc.

[image: screenshot of 3g watchdog]

Additionally extra alerts, for switching mobile data automatically add soon as it exceed allocation

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [Xposed Framework](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811) installed, install the [Advanced Data Plan](http://repo.xposed.info/module/net.m0m4x.android.xposed.advdataplan) module.

This enhances Android's built in data usage meter with a system where you can set the number of days between billing cycles.

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/m0m4x/AdvDataPlan)

[XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xposed-advanced-data-plan-t3634138)

[image: screenshot showing options to set data billing cycle and cycle length in days]