# How to set the Data Billing Cycle to one day in Nougat?

Tags: settings, 7.0-nougat, remix-os

My ISP provides me with 1GB data per day. So the data billing cycle in Nougat would actually make more sense to me if I could somehow make it show the amount of data I've used in a day and then have it reset for the next day.

I'm using Resurrection Remix ROM 5.8.5.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Related: [Weekly mobile usage](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/183511/209414)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use third party app then you can do this by setting usage cycle reset date to current date and you got the track of you current day's usage also can put limit on usage but you have to change it every day manually.